# Help with Wikibooks WikiDraw Obj-C application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I decided to start learning some Obj-C. And I thought that [Wikibooks wikidraw](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming_Mac_OS_X_with_Cocoa_for_Beginners) application would be a good place to start (after some very basic "Hello World" programs). I've followed the chapters and now I'm at the end of "WikiDraws view class". So now I'm supposed to be able to compile and run. Of course it dosen't work. I got a lot of errors at first but i have fixed most of them, only 6 remaining. This is one of them:

```
    - (void)                mouseDragged:(NSPoint) pt

{
    NSPoint np;
    np.x = pt.x - _anchor.x;
    np.y = pt.y - _anchor.y;
    if ( _dragState == 0) {
        // dragging of object
        [self offsetLocationByX:np.x byY:np.y];
        }
     else if ( _dragState >= 1 && _dragState < 9 )
    {
        // dragging a handle
        NSRect nb = [self newBoundsFromBounds:[self bounds] forHandle:_dragState withDelta:np];

        [self setBounds:nb];
        }
    }
```

`- (NSRect) newBoundsFromBounds:(NSRect) old forHandle:(int) whichOne withDelta:(NSPoint) p
{
    // figure out the desired bounds from the old one, the handle being dragged and the new point.
NSRect nb = old;

switch( whichOne )
{ ..........`

So at 
     NSRect nb =  [self newBoundsFromBounds:...
 I get an error message, "Invailid initializer" and "WKDShape may not respond to '-newBoundsFromBounds:forHandle:withDelta:"- . What should I do? I'm new to coding but eager to learn.

/Carl-Philip

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error message you're getting and consider posting the entire source file or project.  Especially when you're getting started, it's pretty hard to tell what portion of your code is causing the error, and it may not be what you think.  (For example your question is already ambiguous—you mention `NSRect nb = ...` but that code occurs twice in the snippet you pasted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've pasted that code in the order written in your source code and newBoundsFromBounds:forHandle:withDelta: isn't declared (as distinct from being defined) at some earlier point, I think the problem is just that at nb = [self newBoundsFromBounds:... the compiler doesn't yet know what the return type will be. An NSRect is a C-style struct rather than an Objective-C class, so the compiler really does need to know.

As a solution, either put the definition of newBoundsFromBounds:... before mouseDragged:, add it to the @interface in your header file if you want it to be exposed to everyone or declare it internally to the implementation file as a category method. To do the final one, add the following to the top of your .m, assuming your class is called WikiDrawsView:

```
@interface WikiDrawsView (private)
- (NSRect)newBoundsFromBounds:(NSRect) old 
                    forHandle:(int) whichOne
                    withDelta:(NSPoint) p;
@end
```

The 'private' is just a name you get to pick, it has no special meaning. Something like 'private' is often used to signify that you're using a category in a similar way that you might use private class member functions in C++ or a language like that.

The quick way to describe categories is that they patch additional methods onto existing classes at runtime, and they use the @interface [classname] ([category name]) syntax, with no member variable section. I'm sure your tutorial will get to them, Apple's documentation on them is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html). This is a common use of categories but not the primary use.

Comment: Thank you it worked great! I had also missed to declare another method but when I did that everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

To address the "WKDShape may not respond" warning, make sure you declare `-newBoundsFromBounds:forHandle:withDelta:` before `-mouseDragged:`. You can add it to the public interface in "WKDShape.h", or in an [anonymous category](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) in "WKDShape.m".